# Android Studio Showing Old GUI While Running Project on the Phone

Tags: android, android-layout, android-studio

I am new to both java and using Android Studio. This is the problem I am facing:

This is the main GUI I created in Android Studio with 2 textBoxes and 1 button and remove the action bar from it:
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SSB2H.png)

And this is the GUI shown after opening the project on my phone. I am currently using Oneplus 3t: 
[IMG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dIS4t.jpg)

Solutions I have tried from stack overflow are:

1. Rebuild the project  (not working)
2. Rerun the project and build (not working)
3. Restart the android studio (not working)

Comment: Please share code of main_activity.xml ?

Comment: disable Instant Run

Answer (score 1):

Try Invalidate Caches.. Goto File->Invalidate Caches/Restart->Choose "Invalidate and Restart".

Also if you have your instant run On, Try after turning it Off.
Go to settings - Search for instant run and uncheck the Enable Instant Run checkbox.

Answer (score 0):

Please check in your activity what layout are you displaying.. if you need to display `activity_main.xml` make sure that that layout is specified in your `setContentView()` method

Answer (score 0):

From the first screenshot, You are using constraint Layout. 
The issue you mentioned occurs when you use constraint layout without giving  any proper constraints.

It looks different in the studio, but when you finally run it without constraints you get the result as shown in your second screenshot.

Add proper constraints to your views.

Comment: How to give them proper constraints vinod can you tell me iam new in Android studio and java

Comment: You can follow  below links for that. https://developer.android.com/training/constraint-layout/index.html       https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/constraint-layout/#9

Comment: Thanks alot vinod with your help i have solved this problem but i have changed the theme to material.light.noactionbar but it is showing action bar again